# The numerical values of the $L$-function of a weight-5 modular form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Suppose $f$ is a weight-5 modular form that is labeled as [27.5.b.a](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/27/5/b/a/) in LMFDB. Let $\chi_3$ be the Dirichlet character
\begin{equation}
\chi_3(p) =\left(\frac{3}{p} \right).
\end{equation}
I want to numerically compute the special values of the $L$-function $L(f \otimes \chi_3, s)$ at $s=1,2,3$. I am trying to use the [Dokchitser’s $L$-functions Calculator](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/lfunctions/sage/lfunctions/dokchitser.html) in Sage. The modular form $f \otimes \chi_3$ should be associated to a pure motive of weight-4 and rank-2, and its Hodge type should be $(4,0)+(0,4)$. So the gamma factor should be $[0,1]$. But I do not know the other invariants of $f \otimes \chi_3$ that are needed by the Dokchitser’s $L$-functions Calculator. Does anyone know how to compute these special values to a very high precision, say the first 100 digits?

Comment: The LMFDB lists the twist of $f$ by $\chi_{3}$ as the weight 5 modular form with label [432.5.e.a](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/432/5/e/a/) and the $L$-function for it is [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/L/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/432/5/e/a/). So the weight should be 5, the conductor is 432, and the sign is 1.

Comment: In Sage, I tried "L = Dokchitser(conductor=432, gammaV=[0,1], weight=5, eps=1,init='1', prec=200)". But the value of L at $s=5/2$ is 2.530840607. However the value of the $L$-function of 432.5.e.a at $s=5/2$ is 1.264584993. Is there something that I have not understood? 432 is the level of this modular form, is the conductor the same as the level?

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand where is the problem. I should include more coefficients of 432.5.e.a in my computation.

Comment: In Pari/GP you can compute the twist of a newform using the command mftwist(f,D). Then you can compute the L-function, it's built-in in Pari/GP.